# Why is my browser commented out the styles inserted in my iFrame

Tags: jquery, css

I'm putting the following code into a page so I can add styles to another page I load into a iframe.  But the browser is commenting out my javascript I get  when I inspect it with Firebug...can someone help?

```
$('#myframe').contents()
   .find("head")
   .append($("#iframe_id").contents()
     .find("head")
     .append("   <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='addStyles.css'/>")
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to edit the contents of an `iframe` from the parent document, because the contents of the `iframe` belongs to a different URL.

You may be able to inject JavaScript into the URL, however. Read this:
http://thetechnofreak.com/technofreak/modify-iframe-with-javascript/

Hope it helps.

Comment: ok.  I'll take a look.  It's src in the iFrame is from the domain which is why I thought it would work.

Comment: yeah I can see why you might think that. I haven't played around with it a huge amount - let me know what you find out.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured out how to do this.  It can't be cross domain (not that I know of yet).

But simple do:
     $(#'myframe').contents().find('head').html(...some style...);

This works just fine for me now.